# R: more efficient solution than this for-loop

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I wrote a functioning for loop, but it's slow over thousands of rows and I'm looking for more efficient alternative. Thanks in advance!

The task:

- If column `a` matches column `b`, column `d` becomes `NA`.
- If column `a` does not match `b`, but `b` matches `c`, then column `e` becomes
  `NA`.

The for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
     if (data$a[i] == data$b[i]) {data$d[i] <- NA}
     if (!(data$a[i] == data$b[i]) & data$b[i] == data$c[i])
        {data$e[i] <- NA}
}
```

An example:

```
a    b    c    d    e
F    G    G    1    10
F    G    F    5    10
F    F    F    2    8
```

Would become:

```
a    b    c    d    e
F    G    G    1    NA
F    G    F    5    10
F    F    F    NA    8
```

Comment: Look into ?ifelse: `data$d <- ifelse(data$a == data$b, NA, data$d); data$e <- ifelse(data$a == data$b & data$b == data$c, NA, data$e)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed and efficiency, I'd recommend `data.table` *(though technically vectorizing a normal `data.frame` as recommended by @parfait would probably speed things up more than enough)*

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread("a    b    c    d    e
             F    G    G    1    10
             F    G    F    5    10
             F    F    F    2    8")
print(DT)
#    a b c d  e
# 1: F G G 1 10
# 2: F G F 5 10
# 3: F F F 2  8

DT[a == b, d := NA]
DT[!a == b & b == c, e := NA]

print(DT)
#    a b c  d  e
# 1: F G G  1 NA
# 2: F G F  5 10
# 3: F F F NA  8
```

Comment: No problem, lots of resources out there for using data.table, but here's a link to the main "Getting Started" page on the official site: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `df` is your data then:

```
ab <- with(df, a==b)
bc <- with(df, b==c)

df$d[ab] <- NA
df$e[!ab & bc] <- NA
```

which would result in

```
#   a b c  d  e
# 1 F G G  1 NA
# 2 F G F  5 10
# 3 F F F NA  8
```

Answer (score 0):

We could create a list of quosure and evaluate it

```
library(tidyverse)
qs <- setNames(quos(d*NA^(a == b), e*NA^((!(a ==b) & (b == c)))), c("d", "e"))
df1 %>%
    mutate(!!! qs)
#  a b c  d  e
#1 F G G  1 NA
#2 F G F  5 10
#3 F F F NA  8
```

Comment: trying to be overkill ?

Comment: @denis Just showing another way.  It would be useful when there are multiple expressions that are already created and wanted to change the data